# Temporary storage of long string data

Tags: c, linux, pipe, std

I am searching for the appropriate way to store a potentially very large string temporarily with a C program using standard libraries on a posix system. The string is the culmination of a linewise output of a C-function. After the last call of this function I want to process (output) the data further. Is there a simple compromise between allocating large amounts of memory and creating a temporary file? For example I could imagine writing to a pipe and reading again from this pipe once the data is needed. But I am not sure how the data would be treated internally in this case and whether it would be prefered over a temporary file.

Answer (score 1):

It mostly depends on what you need to do with the data. If you need to access it randomly (for example if you need to sort it), you may find that to be much easier if the file is all in memory, despite the cost of using potentially large amounts of memory.

Expecially if you are able to access the data sequentially to process it, I would generally recommend a temporary file if you expect the data to be large.

A pipe will not help you unless you create another thread to read the data out of the pipe while your main thread writes it. Otherwise you will just quickly fill up the pipe's buffers and block (deadlock, in fact).

Comment: The data can be both, long and short. Most of the time it will be just a single line, but in the worst case it could even exceed the available physical memory.

Comment: I do not need to access the data randomly but it seems overhead and slow for me to create close open and read a temporary file each time the data is needed for output. Note that I do not need to access the data while it is still produced. So I could write to a pipe, close it, open it again and read but I am not sure what happens to the data in the pipe in this case. I think it is persistent until read. But is it stored in a temp file?

Comment: Well, if the usual case is that the data is short but it's sometimes long, then you could buffer it up in memory until it exceeds a certain size threshold then move it to a temporary file. That's more work for you because you have to handle both cases in your code. Depending on your needs, it may be simpler to accept the overhead and always use a temp file.

Comment: Your pipe proposal makes no sense. Opening a pipe, closing it, and opening it again is not even possible with a normal pipe (you need a named pipe for that), and even if you do it, it doesn't help. If there's no reader, the writer will still block after the (relatively small) buffers are full.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about named pipes. But from glglgl's answer I understood that the buffer is too small.

Answer (score 0):

You could decide (according to your comment, you should decide this on a case-per-case basis) whether to hold it in memory or to write to disk. If you notice that the data grows over a certain threshold, you write to disk and switch the method for the remaining data to put.

A pipe would not be a good idea, as it is a inter-process communication method with very small storage size (about 64kiB since Linux 2.6, in 2.4, it was AFAIR even less - 4 kiB or so).

Comment: Of course! Yet it looks to me as if there should be a standard way to do this.